# List all files that have letter e as nth character in their name - Linux

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu

I want to list all the files having `e` as the nth character in their name in the current directory.

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
find -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^./[e]{5}\.txt$'
```

Answer (score 1):

> want to list all the files having e as the nth character in their name in the current directory.

You may use:

```bash
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^\./.{4}e.*'
```

**Regex breakdown:**

- `^`: Start
- `\./`: Match `./`
- `.{4}`: Match any 4 characters
- `e`: Match letter `e`
- `.*`: Match any text
- `-maxdepth 1` finds entries in current directory only

Or using `print` and glob:

```bash
printf '%s\n' ????e*
```

Here:

- `????`: Match any 4 characters
- `e`: Match `e`
- `*`: Match any text

Comment: @KrShanu: Did this work out?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the standard wildcard stuff from `bash`? As in an example where you want `e` as the fourth character:

```bash
pax.diablo@ubuntu:/home/pax.diablo/test_dir> ls -1d ???e*
ragemix
Makefile
```

That'll expand to any file (in the widest sense of the word) in the current directory starting with three characters followed by an `e`.

Comment: This will find `e` on 4th position. Please check my `printf` solution for the glob pattern

Comment: @anubhava: question asked for `e` as the *n*th character, I chose an `n` of 4 simply because it matched the files I had in my directory. OP's solution only worked for `./eeeee.txt` so it was unclear what `n` should be.